# jamfile: copy files to different directories

Tags: makefile, jam

```
SEARCH_SOURCE = $(DDODBC_LIB_DIR) ;
InstallBin [ FDirName $(TOP) $(BUILDDIR) lib ] : $(DDODBC_LIBS) ;
InstallBin [ FDirName $(TOP) $(BUILDDIR) datadirect V7 lib ] : $(DDODBC_LIBS) ;
```

Only in the second directory can I find the copied files from $(DDODBC_LIBS). Why they are not copied to the first directory by InstallBin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `InstallBin` respectively `InstallInto` need to define a target (per source file) which represents the installed file and which is made a dependency of the `install` pseudo target. They do that by simply using the source target name with the grist set to `$(INSTALLGRIST)`. So the second `InstallBin` invocation defines the same target, resetting the target's location (`LOCATE` variable on the target). Hence the file is only installed to the second location.

A simple, if not particularly elegant, work-around is to redefine `INSTALLGRIST` for one of the invocations of `InstallBin`.

```
SEARCH_SOURCE = $(DDODBC_LIB_DIR) ;

InstallBin [ FDirName $(TOP) $(BUILDDIR) lib ] : $(DDODBC_LIBS) ;

oldInstallGrist = $(INSTALLGRIST) ;
INSTALLGRIST = $(INSTALLGRIST)2 ;
InstallBin [ FDirName $(TOP) $(BUILDDIR) datadirect V7 lib ] : $(DDODBC_LIBS) ;
INSTALLGRIST = $(oldInstallGrist) ;
```

In case you need to do that more often, a more elegant solution would be to create a wrapper rule that derives an `INSTALLGRIST` value from the installation directory:

```
rule InstallBinSafe
{
    local INSTALLGRIST = installed-$(1:G=) ;
    InstallBin $(1) : $(2) ;
}
```

And then simply use that rule instead of `InstallBin`.